# Tridion multi-line text field size limit

Tags: tridion, textfield

I have a situation where the required contents of a multi-line text field exceed the permitted 3,400 bytes that's allowed in the Content Porter (as Peter points out, this limit doesn't apply to the storage of this field in the Component Field CME side - the error is noted below[1]).

The solutions I see are

1. Reduce the size of the content to be less verbose
2. I tried adding maxlength into the schema definition (which would enforce the above!)
3. Use a repeatable field and (either manually or programatically with the event system) split text to maximum sized chunks
4. Seek to extend the limit?

**1's** out - it's a client thing.

**2's** a no-go - I see that this is excluded [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396071/maxlength-restriction-for-multilinetext-field-in-sdl-tridion-2011)

**3's** something I'm considering - I could even use a GUI extension to alert a user [Server side](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.be/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html) code or [Anguilla](http://www.curlette.com/?p=913))

**4's** something I'd like to know if anyone has achieved this through SDL in a supported manner (as we obviously can't just change the field length in the database!)

Thanks for any comments

[1]

```
Destination with name 'HTTPS=[Password=****, URL=http://server.com:81/HTTPUpload.aspx, UserName=removed]' reported the following failure:
A processing error occurred processing a transport package Could not deploy component  [Component id=tcm:11-123-16 title=article_title schema=tcm:11-121-8], Error while creating custom meta data, String or binary data would be truncated., String or binary data would be truncated., Error while creating custom meta data, String or binary data would be truncated., String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question.

Where are you getting this limit of 3 KB from? 
I'm able to save way more than that in a text field. I'm actually not aware of any size limit on fields.

Comment: The only size limit I can think of is after publishing, as a metadata field? If that's the case, contact support, I know we allow _some_ field lenghts to be modified

Comment: I've updated the question - I was informed this was a 'Field' but the error does, indeed, suggest this is a metadata field but we're sure this is an issue with the specific broker field size.

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days of Tridion 2009 SP1 there was a limit due to the size of the database column of 5000 chars.  Any text beyond this was truncated.  Using a repeatable field is not an option because repeatable fields all get stored into the same DB CustomMeta record and are simply comma separated.  The workaround I've used was to create separate fields up to an expected maximum characters that could exist.

I think for your situation with Content Porter you should first go through the available CP hotfixes, else open up a ticket with Support.